# Unable to locate element by giving variable name inside XPATH

Tags: xpath

brand_name = 'LACOSTE'
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()= brand_name]")

This is giving error. However, if i do like this:

element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()= 'LACOSTE']")
then element is found.
But i dont want to hardcode the value. Please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqnfR.jpg)

Comment: Please share the code as text, not as a screenshot. And to get a better understanding it's always best to also share the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath needs apostrophe's around the search-string, so I think you need to concatenate the XPath expression like this

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='" + brand_name + "']")
```